# Shell script double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, quotes

I am writing a shell script that parses a logfile. The important part is this:

```
rx=$(echo "$logfile" | grep -o "rx_value.*" | grep -o "[0-9]\{1,10\}")
echo rx=$rx
```

The following is printed to STDOUT (WRONG):

```
rx=
```

If i remove the double qoutes from $logfile like this:

```
rx=$(echo $logfile | grep -o "rx_value.*" | grep -o "[0-9]\{1,10\}")
echo rx=$rx
```

The following is printed to STDOUT (CORRECT):

```
rx=0
```

I was pretty sure that it was a good thing to use double quotes around variables, so I have used them on all variables in my script. The information I have found so far, says that if one do NOT put double quotes around variables, the result could become wrong because of word splitting, globbing etc.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Edit:

$logfile contains the logfile downloaded with wget:

```
$logfile=(wget -q -O -"http://www.example.com")
```

Comment: What does `$logfile` contain?

Comment: That still doesn't answer Ignacio's question. What is an example of the contents of `$logfile` rather than "where did it come from"?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `logfile` has a newline between `rx_value` and the number you are looking for. The `echo` command with an unquoted parameter expansion will convert the newline to a space. See word splitting or field splitting in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the value of `$logfile`. Your information is correct -- the difference between no quotes and double quotes is precisely field splitting and globbing. So if you rely on one of them to happen, you will get wrong results *with* double quotes.

**UPDATE**. Okay, so your variable containt a log file retrieved with `wget`. May I suggest using a pipe instead?

```
rx=$(wget -q -O -"http://www.example.com" |
     grep -o "rx_value.*" |
     grep -o "[0-9]\{1,10\}")
```

But this will probably output the same that your double-quoted example, and I would trust this more than what you think is correct answer.

Comment: I could try to do some test with that.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you quote the variable on output?

```
echo "rx=$rx"
```

Not doing this is often the source of "mysterious" behavior.

Comment: This also prints the wrong output. Actually the echo line is only for debugging, the value is used elsewhere in the script.